# reportMissingImport error when using FastAPI even when venv activated, pip installed and right interpreter selected

Tags: import, error-handling, fastapi

So I am trying to build my backend application using FastAPI, and first it was working. I activated my venv and pip installed everything and perfect. I kinda remember that I closed my VS code and moved my backend directory(not 100% it was right after I did it), and it just doesn't work anymore.  Kept throwing me the reportMissingImport.

I tried to get a new venv and even deleted the whole project and started another one and it was the same problem...

Comment: Have you selected your new venv as the python interpreter in VS Code?